# Why are foreign characters saving to MySQL server in a funky way?

Tags: php, mysql, database, unicode, localization

I send up the following to my PHP page, which then calls my MySQL server:

```
ethan•test•again
```

but for some reason it gets saved to the database as this:

```
ethanâ€¢testâ€¢again
```

Here is the some partial code in my PHP page that shows me saving the data:

```
if(mysql_query("CALL InsertTitle
(
  '".mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_POST['title']))."'
)"))
```

The interesting thing is that when I call the MySQL server to show the data via another PHP page, it appears just fine. Everything actually works just fine and as expected for me. Here is some sample partial code to pull from the data:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM item WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'");

print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><rss version=\"2.0\"><channel><title>Titles</title>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
  echo "<title>".$row{'title'}."</title>";
}
```

And it appears just fine on the XML page:

```
ethan•test•again
```

Why does it look so funky in my MySQL server? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're not using UTF-8 end-to-end (here's a hint: _[you should be](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)_).

Comment: I dont think you need to use urldecode either...

Comment: For the love of god, please use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of that `str_replace` construct.

Comment: @deceze: don't worry, the str_replace is a null-op anyways. injection attacks have even less than nothing to worry about with this "security" system.

Comment: @Matt Ball: So what end isn't UTF8? The database? I swear I set it to that on install.

Comment: What part of `ethan•test•again` contains a “foreign” character? What makes a character “foreign”? A code point is a code point. Please tell me you aren’t using “foreign” to mean non-ASCII! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `utf8_general_ci` collation in your string table fields and add `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");` after connecting to DB.

Comment: see this article that I wrote yesterday: http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

End **and** end looks fine, its something in the middle.  I get the feeling its just the display that doesn't support the characters.  Where are you looking at the database?  If its console or phpmyadmin, i don't think it would display correctly, even though its saved in utf8.